# Using Flickr API from Java to upload images

Tags: java, file-upload, flickr

I am using a simple Java class to upload images to my account on Flickr using their API. It is all working nicely. However, I would like the description to be more than a short string. The API says some limited HTML is allowed. How would one use that in a Java String (for use in the API) to format (a) line breaks (b) paragraphs (3) even (to be bold) bold or italics?

Comment: What HTML strings have you tried? Did they work?

Comment: @tgdavies See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page at Flickr:

https://www.flickr.com/html.gne

which talks about HTML. It seems to me that it addresses the HTML that can be used in photo descriptions when entered manually. However, the page has the same title ("Some HTML is OK") as in the API documentation, so I tried it in the Java strings used with the Flickr API and they seem to work.

See for example:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/dattatreya/51323912573/in/album-72157719577193992/

The description string used for this is:

```
    String desc = """
            <i>Spirographic</i> Image from
            
            <a href=\"URL\">www.hypknotica.com</a>
            
            uses the <i>Fourier</i> coefficients as follows:
            <blockquote>
            S: 10 ( 0:   1, 1000) ( 2:  21,  394) ( 3:  31,  369) ( 4: -39,  245)
            </blockquote>
            
            See also:
            
            [https://www.flickr.com/photos/dattatreya/51323912573/in/album-72157719577193992/]
            
            
            """;
```

For some reason, I do not see (on the Flickr website) the Flickr image referenced in the description, but I do see it in the comment with the same reference.